# Schema declaration and subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

```js
var ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    category : { type: String, required: true }
});

var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    products: [{
        product: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
        quantity: {type: Number}
    }],
    status: { type: String, required: true }
});

Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
Order = rmongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);

OrderSchema.statics.addOrder = function (data, cb) {
    // data: array of products ID

    var newOrder = new Order();

    data.data.forEach(function(element, index, array) {

        Product.findOne({ '_id': element.id }, function (err, product) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);

            newOrder.products.push({product: product, quantity: element.quantity});
        })
    });

    newOrder.status = 'waiting';

    newOrder.save(function (err, order) {
        if (err) cb(err, false);
        console.log(order);
        var response = json.stringify({
            event: 'addOrder',
            success: true,
            data: order.id
        });

        cb(false, response);

    });
}
```

When i add an order products, array is always empty but i have no error. Maybe it's the wrong to do what i want.

Data send by the client are good and the foreach and findOne work well but push seems doing nothing.

If there is no solution maybe you can try to help me to find another solution.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to wait for all the products to be found.

Try this (untested):

```
OrderSchema.statics.addOrder = function (data, cb) {
    // data: array of products ID

    var newOrder = new Order();

    var productIds = [];
    var quantity = [];

    data.data.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        productIds.push(element.id);
        quantity.push(element.quantity);
    });

    Product.find({ '_id' : { $in: productIds} }, function(err, products) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        products.forEach(function(product, index) {
            newOrder.products.push({product: product, quantity: quantity[index]});
        });

        newOrder.status = 'waiting';
        newOrder.save(function (err, order) {
            if (err) cb(err, false);
            console.log(order);
            var response = json.stringify({
                event: 'addOrder',
                success: true,
                data: order.id
            });

            cb(false, response);
        });
    });
});
```